# Segregate (Group) all the messages of each number(two way)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have a data of conversations between the phone numbers

| from phone | to phone | message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7788994455 | 2233665588 | hi |
| 2233665588 | 7788994455 | hello |
| 1122335566 | 4455117766 | where are you |
| 4455117766 | 1122335566 | I am home |
| 2233665588 | 7788994455 | wassup? |

I am looking to segregate all the messages of each number (two way).

Should be as:-

**Example from the above table:**

7788994455,2233665588:- hi|hello|wassup?

I am looking for the whole conversation should be grouped accordingly(from phone and to phone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do:

```
df['from_to'] = list(zip(df['from'], df['to']))
df['from_to'] = df['from_to'].apply(lambda x:tuple(sorted(x)))
df.groupby('from_to').agg({'message':'|'.join})
```

Output:

```
                                            message
from_to 
(1122335566, 4455117766)    where are you|I am home
(2233665588, 7788994455)           hi|hello|wassup?
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a combined field for both:

```
df['grouper'] = df.apply(lambda x: set([x['from phone'], x['to phone']]), axis=1).astype(str)
```

And do a `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('grouper').agg({'message': ' | '.join})
```

Which will give you following dataframe:

```
                            message
grouper 
{1122335566, 4455117766}    I am home
{2233665588, 7788994455}    hi | hello | wassup?
{4455117766, 1122335566}    where are you
```